How to list files in a directory and select one for reading
I want to read Excel files from a certain directory. However, because the names change I cant use a fixed name. I therefore would like to do the following:

Show which files are in the dir
Select one of them.
Read the file and return.

I set up the part where I list the files
read_BUNQ_data <- function(dir){
 dirs <- list.files(dir)
 print(dirs)
}

Any advice on how I can capture the user input and then open that file?

Using readline().
> f <- \(dir='foo', ...) {
+   x <- list.files(dir, full.names=TRUE)
+   n <- seq_along(x)
+   message(sprintf('Select: %s ', toString(paste0(n, ' = ', basename(x)))))
+   sel <- readline() |> as.integer()
+   openxlsx::read.xlsx(x[sel], ...)
+ }
> 
> f()
Select: 1 = file1.xlsx, 2 = file2.xlsx, 3 = file3.xlsx 
1
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12

In the ... you can pass arguments to read.xlsx, e.g.
> f(startRow=2)
Select: 1 = file1.xlsx, 2 = file2.xlsx, 3 = file3.xlsx 
1
  1 4 7 10
1 2 5 8 11
2 3 6 9 12


Data:
Save to 'foo' directory:
sapply(1:3, \(i) openxlsx::write.xlsx(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)),
                                      sprintf('foo/file%s.xlsx', i))) |> invisible()

